# Fragments should contain more than one child. EsLint Error. If Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint, eslintrc

I currently have this code, but EsLint shows the following error: "Fragments must contain more than one child - otherwise there is no need for a fragment.". But I can't do an IF without wrapping the code in a React.Fragment. Is there another way to remove this error without allowing a lint rule?

```
return (
            <>
                {loading && (
                    <div className={classes.container}>
                        <img
                            alt="loading"
                            src={LoadingAnimation}
                            className={classes.img}
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
            </>
        );
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a way to fix

```
return loading ? (
                    <div className={classes.container}>
                        <img
                            alt="loading"
                            src={LoadingAnimation}
                            className={classes.img}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
                : null;
```

**EDIT**

Since this answer has got some upvotes I'm going to explain further:

In a simple way, a `Fragment` is an element that exists in React component tree, but will not be rendered in DOM. Fragments are useful to when you need to return multiple nodes in a JSX expression.

This is an illegal code:

```
const Component = () => (
  return (
    <div>
       Child 1
    </div>
    <div>
       Child 2
    </div>
  );
);
```

This will bring up the error `JSX expressions must have one parent element`. You could wrap them in another `div` and the error would be gone, but then you end up with another DOM element. But, when you use a `Fragment`, React understands it as a 'parent element', but this element won't appear in DOM tree:

```
const Component = () => (
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
         Child 1
      </div>
      <div>
         Child 2
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
);
```

Also, you can use the shorthand `<>` for the Fragment:

```
const Component = () => (
  return (
    <>
      <div>
         Child 1
      </div>
      <div>
         Child 2
      </div>
    </>
  );
);
```

The error of the question actually consists in using a Fragment to return only one child. It surely works, but it's unnecessary.